# how to place isotope items in a scrollable div and retain jquery hover state effect?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, overflow, jquery-isotope

i am trying to implement three features:

1. a scrollable div containing image thumbnails
2. that can be sorted by jquery isotope
3. that when hovered over display a div on top of other elements and beyond immediate containers.

at the moment i can get either one or the other happening ie either the scrollbars show but then the hover state div is behind other elements, or i can get the hover state div in front of other elements but then the scrollbar does not display.

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/PUKjy/

**script**

```
$(".magic").hover(

function() {
//console.log($(this).find('.hidden_db_data_div').position().left);
console.log($(this).position().top);
$(this).css("z-index", "999").find('.hidden_db_data_div').css({
'left': $(this).position().left + 40 + "px" + "!important",
'top': '-50px'
}).fadeIn(500);

}, function() {
$(this).css('z-index', '').find('.hidden_db_data_div').fadeOut(100);
});
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resolved**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/89P9m/

**code**

```
$(".magic").each(function() {

var hiddenDiv = $(this).find(".hidden_db_data_div"),
parentElement = $(this),
api = {};

api.isOpen = false;

api.timeout = null;

api.position = function(){
hiddenDiv.css({
"top": parentElement.offset().top - $("#wrapper").offset().top - 50,
"left": parentElement.offset().left - $("#wrapper").offset().left +20 
});
}

api.resetTimeout = function(){

clearTimeout( api.timeout );
}

api.startShowing = function(){

api.resetTimeout();

api.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
api.show();        
},300);
}

api.startHiding = function(){

api.resetTimeout();

api.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
api.hide();        
},150);
}
api.show= function(){

if(!api.isOpen){

api.position();

hiddenDiv .fadeIn(500);

api.isOpen = true;

$("#isotope_container").bind("scroll.hiddendiv",api.position);

}
}

api.hide = function(){

if( api.isOpen ) {
api.isOpen = false;
$("#isotope_container").unbind("scroll.hiddendiv");     
hiddenDiv.fadeOut(100);
}

}

hiddenDiv.bind("mouseenter", function() {

api.resetTimeout();

}).bind("mouseleave", function() {

api.startHiding();

}).css("z-index", 100).appendTo("#wrapper"); 

$(this).data("hiddenApi",api );

}).bind("mouseenter", function() {

var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

api.startShowing();

}).bind("mouseleave", function() { // start closing timeout once mouse leaves isotope element

var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

api.startHiding();

});
```